# Found matches if multiple needles

Tags: php

Sorry, I couldn't find the answer to this, but I'm using `str_contains` to find matches of a str within another str.

```
str_contains($haystack, $needle);
```

However, is there a way to have multiple needles or do I need to use this function several times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in function to do this, but you can make your own

```
function str_containsa(string $haystack, array $needles){
    foreach ($needles as $needle){
       if (str_contains($haystack, $needle)){
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

usage

```
str_containsa('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog', ['fox', 'cow', 'goat']); 
//returns true as string contains fox
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can use regex and [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

- [join](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join) needles into pattern string like `(\bneedle1\b)|(\bneedle2\b)` etc
- make regex pattern case insensitive `i` and search multiline `m`

```php
function stringHasWords(string $string, array $needles)
  {
    $nPattern = join('|', array_map(function ($needle) {
      // note \b token 
      return "(\b$needle\b)";
    }, $needles));
    // m - multiline, i - case insensitive
    $pattern = "/$nPattern/mi";
    // returns count of matches or false on error
    $count = preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $count && $count > 0;
  }
```

note that `\b` token makes regex search only exact words, no match for `o` in string `fox`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **preg_match** with **implode** like following :

```
$string = 'some value1 or some value4';

$needles = ['value1','value2','value3','value4'];

if (preg_match("/(?:". implode('|', $needles) .")/", $string)) {
    echo 'does contain';
} else {
    echo 'does not';
}
```

one liner :

```
$doesMatch = preg_match("/(?:". implode('|', $needles) .")/", $string);
```

or as a function :

```
function contain(string $string, array $needles) {
    return preg_match("/(?:". implode('|', $needles) .")/", $string);
}
```